# AJAX.Request POST body not send

Tags: javascript, post, prototypejs

I'm trying to create a POST request, unfortunately the body of the POST never seems to be sent.

Below is the code that I'm using.  The code is invoked when a user clicks on a link, not a form "submit" button.  It runs without error, invokes the servlet that is being called but, as I mentioned earlier, the body of the POST never seems to be sent.

I can validate that the request body is never sent since I have access to the servlet being called.

I've tried using "parameters" in replace of "requestBody."  I've also tried using a parameter string (x=a?y=b).  I've also validated that "ckULK" does contain a valid value.

Any ideas?

```
new Ajax.Request(sURL,
{
    method: 'POST'
    , contentType: "text/x-json"
    , requestBody: {ulk:ckULK}
    , onFailure:
        function(transport)
        {
            vJSONResp = transport.responseText;
            var JSON = eval( "(" + vJSONResp + ")" );
            updateStatus(JSON.code + ": " + JSON.message);
        } // End onFailure
    , onSuccess: 
        function(transport) 
        {
            if (200 == transport.status)
            {
                vJSONResp = transport.responseText;
            }
            else
            {
                log.value += "\n" + transport.status;
            }
         } // End onSuccess
}); // End Ajax.request
```

Comment: When you set up a regular form post, no AJAX involved, does that work in the same situation? I'm asking because if you use IE, there is a non-obvious specialty to be aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the kind of situations where Firebug and Firefox are really helpful. I suggest you install Firebug if you don't have it and check the request that is being sent.

You also definitely need to stick to `parameters` instead of `requestBody`.

This:

```
new Ajax.Request(sURL,
{
    method: 'POST',
    parameters: 'hello=world&test=yes',
    onFailure: function(transport) {
        vJSONResp = transport.responseText;
        var JSON = eval( "(" + vJSONResp + ")" );
        updateStatus(JSON.code + ": " + JSON.message);
    },
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
        if (200 == transport.status) {
            vJSONResp = transport.responseText;
        } else {
            log.value += "\n" + transport.status;
        }
     }
});
```

Should definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the data as **`parameters`** to the Ajax Request constructor:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  parameters: {
    hello: "world", test: "test"
  },
  onSuccess: function(transport){
    var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I hit this problem the solution was to remove `contentType` from `Ajax.Request` options.

In [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216074/1483) by [Paolo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino) `contentType` is not defined in `Ajax.Request` options.

From unknown reasons params defined in `parameters` wasn't sent (FF didn't show them and my server saw empty POST body).

One of my coworkers suggested to use `postBody` instead of `parameters` but I didn't try it.